# Парсинг виртуальной школы

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хочу получить домашку из дневника. Мой код:

```py
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
 
from time import sleep
import requests
 
ua = fake_useragent.UserAgent()
 
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.random}
 
work = Session()
 
work.get('https://www.vsopen.ru/', headers=headers)
 
response = work.get('https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/login?loginerror&redirect_url=', headers=headers)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
 
data = {'login' : 'логин', 'password' : 'пароль'}
 
res = work.post('https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/login?loginerror&redirect_url=', headers=headers, data=data,\
          allow_redirects=True)
 
result1 = work.post('https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/', headers=headers)
 
print(result1.text)
```

На выходе получаю:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
    <head>
        <base href="https://belgorod.vsopen.ru/app/" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
        <title>VSopen.ru :: Виртуальная школа</title>
        <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/css/iestyle.css?2870" />
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/css/style.css?2870"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/css/pretty_table.css?2870"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/css/smartpaginator.css?2870"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/system/tableClone.css?2870"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
 
        <!-- jquery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery.min.js?2870"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.min.js?2870"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/jquery-ui/css/jquery-ui.min.css?2870"/>
 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/lib/moment-with-locales.js?2870"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/lib/moment-timezone.js?2870"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/lib/moment-timezone-data.js?2870"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/lib/soyutils.js?2870"></script>
 
        <!-- underscore -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/lib/underscore-min.js?2870"></script>
 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/globalvsopen.js?2870"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/jquery-redirect/jquery.redirect.js?2870"></script>
 
        <!-- qtip tooltip-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.js?2870"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.css?2870"/>
 
        <!-- chosen -->
        <script src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js?2870" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/chosen/chosen.proto.min.js?2870" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="client/ru/vsopen/system/js/chosen/chosen.min.css?2870"/>
 
        <!--workAreaSelector-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="client/css/system/selectors.css?2870"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/soy/workAreaSelector.js?2870"></script>
 
        <!-- confirm -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/system/confirm.css?2870"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/soy/confirm.js?2870"></script>
 
        <!-- eduTermSelector -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/soy/eduTermSelector.js?2870"></script>
 
        <script>
            var mainParams = {
                baseUrl: '',
                apiUrl: '' + 'api/' + '1'
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_header"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="left">
 
    <div class="widget normal menu" style="width: 81px;">
        <div class="header">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="nw"></div>
        <div class="ne"></div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content js-menu-content">
 
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="w"></div>
        <div class="e"></div>
    </div>
 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/base/menu/css/style.css?2870"/>
 
    <div class="left_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="schedulingLesson" title="Учебное расписание" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite schedulingLesson"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="eduplans" title="Учебные планы" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite eduplans"></div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="left_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="thematicplans" title="Тематическое планирование" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite thematicplans"></div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="left_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="messaging" title="Внутренняя почта" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite messaging"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="notifications" title="Уведомления" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite notifications"></div>
            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="left_menu">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="studentDiary" title="Дневник" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite studentDiary"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="studentportfolio" title="Портфолио ученика" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite studentportfolio"></div>
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-widget="studentReport" title="Табель успеваемости" class="tdn js-menu">
                <div class="widgets-icons-sprite studentReport"></div>
            </a>
    </div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">MENU.init({baseUrl: ''});</script>        </div>
        <div class="footer">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="sw"></div>
        <div class="se"></div>
        <div class="s"></div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="minblocks"></div>
            <div id="normalblocks">
    <div id="wx0" class="widget normal start js-start-widget" style="width: 600px;">
        <div id="wx0_module" class="start"></div>
        <div class="header">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="nw"></div>
        <div class="ne"></div>
    </div>
            <div class="widget_header">
                <h2>Добро пожаловать, Гринко Ярослав Владимирович.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        WIDGET.initWidget({baseUrl: '', prefix: 'wx0', widget: 'start'});
    </script>
 
        <div class="button-border"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close js-widget-close" title="Закрыть"></a>
 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="w"></div>
        <div class="e"></div>
    </div>
            <div class="js-widget-loaders">
                <div id="wx0_loader" class="loader"></div>
                <div id="wx0_divloader" class="divloader"></div>
            </div>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/system/importExport.css?2870"/>
 
 
    <div class="import-export-panel">
 
        <script>
            IMPORT_EXPORT_PANEL.init({
                baseUrl: '',
                prefix: 'wx0',
                widget: 'start'
            });
        </script>
 
    </div>
 
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/base/start/css/main.css?2870" />
 
 
    <div class="selected6 err newsHeader">
        Уважаемые пользователи!<br/>
    </div>
 
    <div class="selected6 news">
        <h3 class="b err">Доступен переход на новый учебный год 2022/2023. Вы можете скачать файл с руководством на стартовом виджете кликом по ссылке &quot;Порядок перехода на новый учебный год&quot;.</h3>
    </div>
 
<span class="tar db">
        <a class="downloadLink b" href="client/files/Переход на новый учебный год.docx" target="_blank">
            Порядок перехода на новый учебный год
        </a>
        <a class="downloadLink b" href="client/files/ИСОУ Виртуальная школа. Руководство.zip" target="_blank">
            Скачать руководство пользователя
        </a>
        <a class="downloadLink " href="client/files/edu_term_course.pdf" target="_blank">
            Инструкция по добавлению курса, не рассчитанного на полный учебный год
        </a>
        <a class="downloadLink " href="client/files/Учет посещаемости учеников.pdf" target="_blank">
            Учет посещаемости учеников
        </a>
        <a class="downloadLink " href="client/files/Руководство_по_контролю_домашнего_задания.pdf" target="_blank">
            Руководство по контролю домашнего задания
        </a>
        <a class="downloadLink " href="client/files/Руководство_Уведомления.pdf" target="_blank">
            Руководство по работе в виджете &quot;Уведомления&quot;
        </a>
</span>
 
    <div class="section" title="Классы">
        <div class="section-content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Учебное расписание"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite schedulingLesson js-start"
                           data-widget="schedulingLesson"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Учебное расписание</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Учебные планы"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite eduplans js-start"
                           data-widget="eduplans"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Учебные планы</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" title="Образовательный процесс">
        <div class="section-content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Тематическое планирование"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite thematicplans js-start"
                           data-widget="thematicplans"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Тематическое планирование</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" title="Сервис">
        <div class="section-content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Внутренняя почта"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite messaging js-start"
                           data-widget="messaging"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Внутренняя почта</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Уведомления"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite notifications js-start"
                           data-widget="notifications"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Уведомления</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" title="Успеваемость">
        <div class="section-content">
            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Дневник"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite studentDiary js-start"
                           data-widget="studentDiary"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Дневник</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Портфолио ученика"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite studentportfolio js-start"
                           data-widget="studentportfolio"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Портфолио ученика</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Табель успеваемости"
                           class="widgets-icons-sprite studentReport js-start"
                           data-widget="studentReport"
                           data-id=""
                        >
                            <span>Табель успеваемости</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">START.init({baseUrl: '', prefix: 'wx0'});</script>
<div class="cb"></div>        </div>
        <div class="footer">
    <div class="borders">
        <div class="sw"></div>
        <div class="se"></div>
        <div class="s"></div>
    </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/css/system/confirm.css?2870"/>
<!--в данных инпутах содержится информация для подтверждений-->
<input value="start" type="hidden" id="wx0_widgetName"/>
 
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div id="header">
                <a href=""></a>
                <div id="sidebarblock" class="js-side-bar">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client/ru/vsopen/base/sideBar/css/style.css?2870"/>
 
<div class="top_menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu_li js-side-bar-element">
            <div class="tmr">
                <a class="js-side-bar-link" data-widget="start" href="javascript:void(0);">Начать работу</a>
            </div>
        </li>
            <li class="menu_li js-side-bar-menu">
                <div class="tmr">
                    <span>Классы</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub hid js-side-bar-sub-menu">
                    <div class="cont">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="schedulingLesson">
                                    <span>Учебное расписание</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="eduplans">
                                    <span>Учебные планы</span>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_li js-side-bar-menu">
                <div class="tmr">
                    <span>Образовательный процесс</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub hid js-side-bar-sub-menu">
                    <div class="cont">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="thematicplans">
                                    <span>Тематическое планирование</span>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_li js-side-bar-menu">
                <div class="tmr">
                    <span>Сервис</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub hid js-side-bar-sub-menu">
                    <div class="cont">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="messaging">
                                    <span>Внутренняя почта</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="notifications">
                                    <span>Уведомления</span>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="menu_li js-side-bar-menu">
                <div class="tmr">
                    <span>Успеваемость</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sub hid js-side-bar-sub-menu">
                    <div class="cont">
                        <ul>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="studentDiary">
                                    <span>Дневник</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="studentportfolio">
                                    <span>Портфолио ученика</span>
                                </li>
                                <li class="js-side-bar-element js-side-bar-link" data-widget="studentReport">
                                    <span>Табель успеваемости</span>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">SIDE_BAR.init({baseUrl: ''});</script>
                </div>
                <div id="timer" class="timer">
                    20:13
                </div>
                <div class="js-session_dialog_window">
                    <div class="in hid js-session-dialog-text">
                        <div class="modal-header student__header clearfix">
                            <span class="modal-title">Уважаемый пользователь!</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                В целях безопасности сеанс работы завершен, т.к. длительное время вы не
                                совершали никаких действий.
                                Для продолжения работы введите, пожалуйста, заново ваши логин и пароль.
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="js-right-panel right-panel">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="client/css/system/rightPanel.css?2870"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="client/js/soy/notificationPanel.js?2870"></script>
 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Личный кабинет" class="js-right-panel-person">
        <div class="widgets-icons-sprite persons"></div>
    </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Уведомления" class="js-right-panel-notification right-panel-notification">
            <div class="widgets-icons-sprite notifications">
                <span class="right-panel-notification-counter js-right-panel-notification-counter hid">0</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Внутренняя почта" class="messaging js-right-panel-messaging">
        0
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Выход" class="js-right-panel-logout logout"></a>
 
    <div class="js-right-panel-notification-modal right-panel-notification-modal">
        <div class="in hid js-right-panel-notification-modal-in">
            <div class="modal-header student__header clearfix">
                <span class="modal-title">Новое уведомление!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="js-right-panel-notification-modal-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">RIGHT_PANEL.init({baseUrl: ''});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        NOTIFICATION_PANEL.init({
            baseUrl: '',
            baseApiUrl: 'api/1'
        });
    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Блок отвечающий за домашку пустой( и на 422 строчке:
`В целях безопасности сеанс работы завершен, т.к. длительное время вы не совершали никаких действий. Для продолжения работы введите, пожалуйста, заново ваши логин и пароль.`
Сайт походу видит, что я бот. Переход на селениум не рассматриваю. Буду рад любой помощи и фидбэку.

Comment: если там есть на поддержку клиентом js-скриптов, то BS бесполезен, на сколько я знаю. попробуйте посмотреть какие fetch запросы идут на сервер, возможно получится подергать API

Comment: data = {'redirect': '', 'login' : 'логин', 'password' : 'пароль'}

Comment: @СергейШ резутьтат тот же.

Comment: @Dmitry подскажите, что именно нужно сделать?

Comment: @yaroslaveq как уже предложил человек выше, можно открыть консоль разработчика и во вкладке Network посмотреть, какие с этой страницы отправляются запросы на сервер. Если домашка дёргается JS через AJAX - оно там должно быть.

Comment: @yaroslaveq если же страница полностью статичная и домашка отправляется сразу в её составе, минуя подгрузку через всякие скрипты - в той же вкладке Network можно как раз скопировать заголовки, которые отправляет браузер при запросе страницы. Возможно, если скопировать их полностью, получится избежать ограничений сайта.

Comment: @yaroslaveq если нужно будет скопировать какой-то из запросов, это можно сделать через ПКМ по нему -> "copy is cUrl (bash). Потом есть сайты, ищутся в два клика, которые конвертируют curl в другие языки - там же есть и requiests из python. Копируется и запрос, и все заголовки разом. =)

Comment: @yaroslaveq на самый крайний случай, если придёт отчаяние и единственным выходом таки останется selenium - его всегда можно переключить в headless режим, чтобы глаз не мозолил. Потребление ресурсов, конечно, всё равно никуда не денется.

Comment: @witaway идея с сайтом и cUrl мега крутая, буду пользоваться. Но сейчас не помогло - результат тот же. Еще пробовал брать и добавлять запросы из нетворк, тоже не помогло. Может есть идеи, что еще посмотреть? Я могу скринами кинуть или просто доступ к виртуалке дать

Comment: По поводу cUrl, не нужны никакие сайты, для этого есть Postman. По поводу Selenium, для этого есть HTTPX и куча других библиотек, хватит насиловать Selenium, он не для этого. Более чем уверен, что можно обойтись обычным requests, но потестить не могу.